# Check if value exists in firebase DB with Django

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my Firebase DB:

```
    {
  "users": {
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "Peter",
      "ID": "U1EL9SSUQ",
      "username": "peter01"
    },
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "John",
      "ID": "U1EL5623",
      "username": "john.doe"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check if ID with value U1EL5623 exists using **Django**.

```
all_users = db.child('users').get(user['idToken'])
for user in all_users.each():
    if user.ID == "U1EL9SSUQ":
        print(user.username)
```

And i have this error `'Pyre' object has no attribute 'ID'`

Regards./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution for my problem, and this work fine.

```
        all_users = db.child('users').get(user['idToken'])
        for user in all_users.each():
            if user.val().get("ID") == "U1EL9SSUQ":
                print(user.val().get("username"))
```

Thanks./